# Uncaught TypeError: switchEditors.switchto is not a function

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg

I have the following line of code:

```
switchEditors.switchto(ctmce[0]);
```

which gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: switchEditors.switchto is not a function
```

Searching around I [found out](https://github.com/anteprimorac/js-wp-editor/issues/3) that, due to changes to the core in WordPress 4.3, `switchEditors.switchto()` is not available/usable now.

Do you know how can I fix it?

You can see the complete code [here](https://github.com/spencercarli/bedrock-fun/blob/3de219c92d0cdf58edd85dda81e6bde23f2cfcf0/web/app/themes/Nevada-Responsive/nevada/lambda/assets/js/lambda.pttiny.js#L328).

Comment: Unfortunately support regarding third-party plugins is off-topic here. It looks like the plugin responsible has not been updated for six years, however - for security and compatibility's sake, it would be best to find an alternative.

Comment: @bosco I agree it would be better to find an alternative instead of using a not supported theme. But it would be also interesting to find out the purpose of `switchEditors.switchto()` and how it was changed in latest versions of WordPress.

Comment: It was a function which executed when the "Code"/"Visual" buttons were clicked in the old TinyMCE editor interface to affect the swap between editors. I believe it was replaced with `switchEditors.switchEditor()`. [Here's the relevant file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/editor.js).